# free disk space via cmd batch file

Tags: cmd

need a cmd command to use it in batch file to get free disk space on C drive after and before removing some folders in .txt format or need to know a space for specific folders and also export it in .txt folder

Comment: Interesting question, but it may be more suited to the Super User site : http://superuser.com since it is cmd based.

Answer (score 0):

Since cmd.exe's `set /A`-math is limited to signed 32bit integers, you could get into trouble calculating free space on an empty 4TB drive. A way around is to use PowerShell for the calcuation.

```
@Echo off

For /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value'
) Do Set FS1=%%A

:: Delete something
Del /F /A /Q /S "%tmp%\*" >Nul 2>&1

For /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value'
) Do Set FS2=%%A

set FS
:: Let PowerShell do the calculating
powershell.exe "\"{0,10} GB freed\" -f [math]::round(($env:FS2-$env:FS1)/(1GB),2)"
```

Sample output:

```
FS1=87454994432
FS2=85188575232
     2,11 GB freed
```